# How does memory work in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memory

I'm trying to understand the idea behind **memory usage in Ruby**. I'm currently going through memory issues on my Rails web app and API.

Here's a simple question:

If I load many records inside a variable like so:

```
users = User.where(work: 'cook')
```

This would probably hold in my app's memory for the time I'm using this variable, right?

But would it help to free memory by doing the following after I'm done using the variable in my code?

```
users = nil
```

Thank you for your help. I'm also open to answers that answer the question on a broader topic.

Comment: Could you provide an example for a variable that persists after you are done using it?

Comment: Setting to `nil` is like telling explicitly that `users` is not referenced anywhere and can be collected on next GC cycle. However, there shouldn't be any need of this, as GC's incremental mark and sweep algo automatically figures out when a variable goes out of scope for it to be collected. Read more about GC in ruby here - https://blog.heroku.com/incremental-gc

Comment: @Stefan I'm not sure how to check if that's the case. I'm currently investigating why I have memory issues and after looking for leaks everywhere I started wondering about this.

Comment: @Hugo can you be more specific? What do you mean by "memory issues"? Neither Ruby nor Rails are lightweight.

Comment: @Stefan By issues I mean I regularly go over my current Heroku plan on the memory side so I suspect my code has some memory leaks somewhere. Anyway, I had this very specific question in mind.

Comment: @Hugo please remember that memory allocation and memory leaks are different your application does not need to be leaking (and probably isn't) for your memory allocation to spike `User.all.to_a` might (depending on the number of users) be allocating a lot of memory to build and store that `Array` but that does not mean that it is leaking it

Comment: @Hugo since you're on Heroku, I'd recommend using something like NewRelic to see exactly where the bottlenecks are in your application. This will give you good insight to know where your memory spikes are coming from.

Answer (score 1):

Yes setting users to nil would indeed reduce required memory (very slightly) but it's not necessary as the Garbage Collector will eventually sweep it. In production you should assume your Ruby process will always grow over time and should be periodically restarted if your concerned about memory management. The maximum heap space reduction you'll ever see in ruby is minimal compared to its growth over time so I wouldn't concern yourself with setting large collections to nil to save a few bytes here and there a little earlier than the GC would have swept it anyway.  Ruby allocates objects in a heap space that consists of heap pages.  Assuming you're using Ruby2.1 or better, the heap space is divided into used (aka Eden) and empty (aka Tomb) heap pages.  When instantiating objects, ruby looks for free space in the eden pages first and only if no space is available will it take a page from tomb.  When you then overwrite the object with nil, those heap pages are added back to the tomb.  Moving pages from the eden to the tomb will reduct heap size slightly however Ruby's Garbage Collector won't drastically reduce it because it assumes if you've created a large collection of objects before, you'll do it again. One book I recommend diving into is "Ruby Performance Optimization" as it goes through ruby's Garbage Collector in depth.